# Capistrano MUTEX - block concurrent executions

Tags: capistrano, mutex

We're using Capistrano 3.0 and enabling our devs to do deploys from their own machines with their own user accounts to various servers.

We have a need to block concurrent execution (singleton, mutex pattern.. etc).

Our current idea is to place a 'lock' file on the target at the beginning of deploy, and then clean up file lock after :finished.  However, if an exception is thrown, the :finished code is never reached.  I'm experimenting with begin, rescue, ensure to delete the file lock, but I really hate to wrap all our deployment code with this.

Any ideas how we can block concurrent deployments on a given target machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a `deploy:failed` task that Capistrano executes if the deploy fails for whatever reason. You can perform your cleanup there.

You can also search GitHub for the terms "capistrano" and "lock" to see how some other people have approached this problem. I don't think any of those projects are currently maintained, though.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I made use of the deploy:failed hook as well as basing my locking mechanism on a few Capistrano locking projects found on github `after "deploy:failed", :custom_error_handler do
    puts "error caught"
  end`

Comment: @HireNickSkitch glad to help! Does this mean you'll accept my answer? :)